# How to add and show server's configuration in node using sparx enterprise architect's deployment diagram

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect

When I am using Sparx Enterprise Architect to do deployment modeling, How do I add and show the server's configuration? like the following image, the left is from the example model, and got the configuration, but when I create an instance of the same server, nothing is showed up there. Both are instances of **Dell PowerEdge 2650**.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you search for is [defining a Run-Time Variable](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/modeling_languages/definearuntimevariable.html).

As an alternative (or additionally), you could use [tagged values](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/9.3/modeling_basics/addtaggedvalues.html).

Comment: Wayback doesn't have it but this should still help: http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/10/standard_uml_models/definearuntimevariable.html